# For Loop Returning Empty Lists

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull all of the brands from the links in `sptct_links` using the function `pull_Brand`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

opts = Options()
opts.headless=True
assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
browser = Firefox(options=opts)

sptct_links =['https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Productsperpage/120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/2,120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/3,120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/4,120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/5,120?id=16499']

def pull_Brand(url):
    browser.get(url)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    brand = []
    for tag in soup.find_all(class_='productBrand'):
        brand.append(tag.text.strip())
    print(brand)

for i in range(len(sptct_links)):
        pull_Brand(sptct_links[i])

browser.quit()
```

While it successfully appends the information in the list `brand` for `sptct_links[0]`, the subsequent lists are returning empty. Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just tested it, you aren't appending to brand because it can't find 'productBrand'.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access the requested URL on this server.
<p>Reference: 18.95952f17.1593528432.1f2131d8</p>

</body></html>

got this when using chrome driver. for links 2-5. link 1 working fine.

Comment: You may be running into a rate limiter that blocks you from downloading multiple pages rapidly. They don't want people writing web scrapers like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `opts=headless=True` option, you will see the following errors for subsequent links:

> Access Denied
> You don't have permission to access the requested URL on this server.
>
> Reference: 18.3d702617.1593528484.1aacf782

If you were to change the order of links in your list, whatever is first will work but the subsequent ones will fail. So, there is nothing wrong with the links per se. My guess is that the website is detecting that the browser is being run by automation (Selenium) and is only allowing you that one one page web access.

I put a 5 second pause between page fetches and still got the errors on all fetches except the first page, so it is not a question of the rate of fetching.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! Wouldn't have necessarily considered that, but makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To get correct page, set `User-Agent` Http header in your request.

For example:

```
sptct_links =['https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Productsperpage/120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/2,120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/3,120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/4,120?id=16499',
        'https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Pageindex,Productsperpage/5,120?id=16499']

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

for link in sptct_links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')  # <-- set headers=

    for brand in soup.select('.productBrand'):
        print(brand.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Michael Kors
MICHAEL Michael Kors
Michael Kors
Bar III
Bar III
Bar III
Unlisted by Kenneth Cole
Tallia
Michael Kors
Bar III

...and so on.
```

Comment: Incredible, this is really helpful! Thank you!